# Enable SSL between GUACD and Guacamole web server (Tomcat)

Tags: docker, ssl, tomcat, guacamole

i'm trying to figure out how and where to set right configuration to get working SSL beetween guacd and server guacamole (tomcat web srv).

I am using docker solution environment and i am bit confused where put right configuration. Let me explain what i've understood and hope someone can clarify me.

- guacamole.properties and guacd.conf has to be on same $GUACAMOLE_HOME dir (guacamole container)? or guacamole.properties has to be put inside guacamole container and guacd.conf inside guacd container? (If Yes, under which directory, in guacd container?)

Below container commands :

`docker run --name guacd_ssl --restart=always -v /opt/docker_data/guacd:/opt/local -e GUACD_LOG_LEVEL=debug -p 57822:4822 -d guacamole/guacd`

`docker run --name guacamole-1.2.0-SSL --restart=always -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole_db -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e --link guacd_ssl:guacd --link db_guacamole:mysql -v /opt/docker_data/guacamole:/opt/local -e GUACAMOLE_HOME=/opt/local -e GUACD_PORT=57822 -e GUACD-SSL=true -d -p 8090:8080 guacamole/guacamole:latest`

Now, certificates where are to be putted? in /opt/docker_data/guacamole (host dir) or into /opt/docker_data/guacd (host dir) ?

Configuration files:

guacd.conf

```
[ssl]

server_certificate = /opt/local/cert.pem
server_key = /opt/local/key.pem
```

guacamole.properties

`guacd-ssl: true`

Can you help me understand?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable SSL for guacd in docker environment, you will need to copy SSL certificate and key into the guacd container. You can do so by creating a customized image atop of the guacd image or via volume mount. If you want to take the first option, you can find guacd `Dockerfile` at [here](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-server/blob/master/Dockerfile).

`guacamole-properties` and `guacd.conf` are two different files.

`guacamole-properties` is the configuration file for **guacamole-client** while `guacd.conf` is the configuration file for **guacamole-server(guacd)**. Usually, you will place both files in `/etc/guacamole/`. For docker, the situation is slightly different.

In docker, the default `GUACAMOLE_HOME` for the guacamole-client container is located at `/root/.guacamole`. You can find the `guacamole.properties` file here.

For guacd, you can place your `guacd.conf` in `/etc/guacamole/`.

For the certificate and key, you can place it anywhere you like as long as you mentioned the path in `guacd.conf`.

Comment: Hi, you said ti Place guacd.conf under /etc/guacamole. Ok, but in wichc container? I am using 2 different container, One for guacamole client and One for guacamole server.

Comment: Solved! I had to create /etc/guacamole folder under "guacd container" and put guacd.conf under that folder. Then all is running now! Thank you @Song for your hints.